# Azure SingalR Service connection ended without reason on Blazor Server App

Tags: signalr, blazor-server-side, azure-signalr

We have a Blazor Server App which is connected to the Azure SignalR Service. More or less randomly we get a disconnect and our clients need to reload to establish the connection again. I added logs to the client and server side to find the reason, but the logs of the SignalR Service tells me only 'Connection ended. Reason: '. Have anyone an idea when this can happen?

All my configurations should avoid that the server close the connection. It should only happen when the client is really long offline.
Server Config:

```
services
     .AddSignalR(e =>
     {
         e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10240000;                  
         e.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
         e.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
     })
     .AddAzureSignalR(o =>
     {
         o.ConnectionString = $"Endpoint=https://{signalRHostName};AccessKey={signalRAccessKey};Version=1.0;";
         o.ServerStickyMode = ServerStickyMode.Required;
     });

services
    .AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
    {
        options.DetailedErrors = true;
        options.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 500;
        options.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    })
    .AddHubOptions(options =>
    {
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10240000;
        options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    })
    .AddCircuitOptions(options =>
    {
        options.DetailedErrors = true;
        options.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 500;
        options.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    });
```

I use dotnet core 5.0 and
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client Version=5.0.10
Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Version=1.11.0

The app is running in a kubernetes cluster on the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 image.

When a disconnect happen, the client show the following logs:

```
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.471Z] Information: Starting up blazor server-side application.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.474Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://my_url/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.475Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.476Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Binary'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.477Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://my_url/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.543Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://signalr-production.service.signalr.net/client/negotiate?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=DAHRmI%2B1AAA%3D&asrs_lang=de.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.770Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.889Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://signalr-production.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=DAHRmI%2B1AAA%3D&asrs_lang=de&id=Q86RxsprcCJfeqXYmHYn-w16caeea61&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY3MzUzOTUyNCIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhc3JzLnMuc24iOiJocS1ibGF6b3ItcHJvZHVjdGlvbi02NTY0NTg5NDk4LWh3Mjc4XzcxMzU1ODYyMWQ5ZjRiNzNiNjgxYzExZGM4Y2RiZDdlIiwiYXNycy5zLnNzdGlja3kiOiJSZXF1aXJlZCIsImFzcnMucy5jaHQiOiIzMCIsIm5iZiI6MTYzMjgyMjM1NiwiZXhwIjoxNjMyODI1OTU2LCJpYXQiOjE2MzI4MjIzNTYsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vaHEtc2lnbmFsci1wcm9kdWN0aW9uLnNlcnZpY2Uuc2lnbmFsci5uZXQvY2xpZW50Lz9odWI9Y29tcG9uZW50aHViIn0.HyJ6gtHT-KpGmSF5RWYzYg-mjHWBxbMG3XWwk-KJG1g.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.889Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.890Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.890Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'blazorpack'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.947Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.947Z] Debug: HubConnection connected successfully.
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.997Z] Debug: Received render batch with id 2 and 3470 bytes.
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:45:56.998Z] Debug: Applying batch 2.
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:45:57.002Z] Information: Blazor server-side application started.
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:45:57.125Z] Debug: Received render batch with id 3 and 84 bytes.
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:45:57.125Z] Debug: Applying batch 3.
...
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:45:59.204Z] Debug: Received render batch with id 35 and 72 bytes.
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:45:59.204Z] Debug: Applying batch 35.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:27.231Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ().) called while in state Connected.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:27.231Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ().'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:27.231Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ().) called while in state Connected.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.530Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://my_url/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.531Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.532Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Binary'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.533Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://my_url/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.665Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://signalr-production.service.signalr.net/client/negotiate?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=eF3f5uq1AAA%3D&asrs_lang=de.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.859Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.943Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://signalr-production.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=eF3f5uq1AAA%3D&asrs_lang=de&id=DMjWjXZKU6NyGnM8O2EiyQdf92f9231&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY3MzUzOTUyNCIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhc3JzLnMuc24iOiJocS1ibGF6b3ItcHJvZHVjdGlvbi02NTY0NTg5NDk4LWh3Mjc4XzcxMzU1ODYyMWQ5ZjRiNzNiNjgxYzExZGM4Y2RiZDdlIiwiYXNycy5zLnNzdGlja3kiOiJSZXF1aXJlZCIsImFzcnMucy5jaHQiOiIzMCIsIm5iZiI6MTYzMjgyMjc0OCwiZXhwIjoxNjMyODI2MzQ4LCJpYXQiOjE2MzI4MjI3NDgsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vaHEtc2lnbmFsci1wcm9kdWN0aW9uLnNlcnZpY2Uuc2lnbmFsci5uZXQvY2xpZW50Lz9odWI9Y29tcG9uZW50aHViIn0.tkoeJaQVyFgMrmfJiuIPQN282738RPeM7jM5gmiVuGM.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.943Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.943Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.944Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'blazorpack'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.973Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:52:28.974Z] Debug: HubConnection connected successfully.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:48.794Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Disconnecting.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:48.795Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:48.795Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.) called while in state Connected.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:50.927Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://my_url/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:50.928Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:50.928Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Binary'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:50.928Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://my_url/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.010Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://signalr-production.service.signalr.net/client/negotiate?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=bVppNieNAQA%3D&asrs_lang=de.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.178Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.268Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://signalr-production.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=bVppNieNAQA%3D&asrs_lang=de&id=2mCRE3qHKZ-FnDMck9-LSAba427abb1&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ii02OTYwODgxMzciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhc3JzLnMuc24iOiJocS1ibGF6b3ItcHJvZHVjdGlvbi02NTY0NTg5NDk4LThjZHM3XzQyODJhNDNjNWQ2YTQyYTQ5ZGFkMzE3ZTFjNzhkMGY0IiwiYXNycy5zLnNzdGlja3kiOiJSZXF1aXJlZCIsImFzcnMucy5jaHQiOiIzMCIsIm5iZiI6MTYzMjgyMjk1MSwiZXhwIjoxNjMyODI2NTUxLCJpYXQiOjE2MzI4MjI5NTEsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vaHEtc2lnbmFsci1wcm9kdWN0aW9uLnNlcnZpY2Uuc2lnbmFsci5uZXQvY2xpZW50Lz9odWI9Y29tcG9uZW50aHViIn0.uFLZtwH-2w_O5iv4RpSHjGcdOVV9TjbdP3b7UJ4lEZQ.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.268Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.269Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.269Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'blazorpack'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.297Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.298Z] Debug: HubConnection connected successfully.
blazor.server.js:21 [2021-09-28T09:55:51.325Z] Information: Reconnection attempt to the circuit was rejected by the server. This may indicate that the associated state is no longer available on the server.
```

And the SignalR tells me:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "message": "Connection ended. Reason: ",
        "collection": "Connection",
        "type": "ConnectivityLogs",
        "connectionId": "N-JNGUfa5E-6DH25zn41Iwdf92f9231",
        "userId": null,
        "transportType": "WebSockets",
        "connectionType": "Client"
    },
    "operationName": "ConnectionEnded",
    "category": "AllLogs",
    "level": "Informational",
    "callerIpAddress": "91.11.173.57",
    "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/....",
    "time": "2021-09-28T09:36:49Z",
    "location": "germanywestcentral"
}
```

Has anyone an hint for me, how I get detailed logs about the connection end or if maybe something wrong in my configuration. My goal is the reduce the disconnection as much as possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please share what was the problem with the disconnections.